# visual studio vb - Convert cell (Excel) address from "C15" to Row = 15 and Column = 3

Tags: excel, vb.net, reference

I have a simple application that is required to access Excel files, inject some data into selected cells, and retrieve calculated results from yet another cell.

All cells references are received in the form `<letter(s)><number>` (e.g. G35).

The problem is that the way to access the cells within Visual Studio (as far as I could find) is by using Row and Column values.

Is there a simple way to convert letter-number format to Row-Column format? Or, alternatively, access cells using the letter-number format.

Comment: If you use the `Worksheet.Range` object, you can specify cell(s) by Excel cell references

Comment: Yes @SSS That's exactly what I found few minutes after posting the question. Wanted to delete the question but you were too quick :-). I'll flag it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Worksheet.Range object, you can specify cell(s) by Excel cell references

To convert a 0-based column index to the equivalent column heading, use the following:

```
Private Function xlCol(ByVal col As Integer) As String
  'col -= 1 'Uncomment this line if you are using 1-based column indices
  Dim s As String = ""
  If col < 0 Or col > 16383 Then
    Throw New ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} is an invalid column", col), "col")
  End If
  If col >= 26 ^ 2 Then
    s = Chr(64 + (col \ 26 \ 26) Mod 26)
  End If
  If col >= 26 Then
    s &= Chr(64 + (col \ 26) Mod 26)
  End If
  s &= Chr(65 + (col Mod 26))
  Return s
End Function
```

According to [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), an Excel spreadsheet cannot have more than 16384 columns (column index 16383 or heading XFD).